# Which Chinese font is commonly supported by PDF readers of Chinese people?

Tags: pdf, fonts

I am generating PDF files which contain English and Chinese characters (using the Ruby Prawn library). I don't want to embed a Chinese font file in the generated PDF files, because these files need to stay small. So I'm wondering if I could just mentioning a Chinese font name in my PDF files, and have the PDF readers correctly rendering the Chinese characters because the PDF readers would already have the Chinese font file.

Is that something sensible? If so is there any commonly used Chinese font that one can expect to be installed in most of the PDF readers used by Chinese people?

Comment: No. The standard set of guaranteed fonts are for Latin1 only (well, plus Poor Man's Greek with Symbol, and the original Zapf Dingbats which are only useful for its nice bullets). All other fonts need to be embedded or present on the user's system.

Comment: thanks, did not know about font subset, I've applied that and it works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to ensure that a PDF file can be displayed on a any reader, is to use partially embedded fonts (also known as font subset). In PDF, you don't need to include the whole font with your document, having a subset with just the glyphs that were used in the file is enough for the file to be portable.

Comment: A font supporting various Asian character sets at once is "Arial Unicode MS" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS

Comment: @Florent2 That font takes more than 20Mb of space, fully-embedding such font will not produce small files as you originally requested.

Comment: I generate PDF files using this font with Prawn and it still produces small files, seems that Prawn only includes the used characters.